# How to make dynamic-height-images not overlap?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am doing something like below. Both images have dynamic/variable height based on `blockHeaderImg` and `blockFooterImg` parameters.

What I want is to have the 2nd image to start right where the 1st ended.
Something like `display: block` on `CSS`.

```
<summary>
    <band height="2">
        <image scaleImage="RealHeight" isUsingCache="true" onErrorType="Blank">
            <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="500" height="1" uuid="c0b2f2c0-6a77-11e6-8b77-86f30ca893d3" />
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{blockHeaderImg}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
        <image scaleImage="RealHeight" isUsingCache="true" onErrorType="Blank">
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="500" height="1" uuid="00045792-07db-11e7-93ae-92361f002671" />
            <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{blockFooterImg}]]></imageExpression>
        </image>
    </band>
</summary>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I am doing this manually, no IDE for jasper.

Comment: Try to make `positionType="FixRelativeToTop"` for 2nd image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `positionType="Float"` for the image at y=1.

Comment: Thanks for this! I totally missed this attribute.